# Convert string to number in typescript without losing leading zero without using an array solution

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need to split a string of numbers and convert to number. converted strings must not reduced or something.
For example when i use to convert `"01" in string` to `01 in number` like below, i got something wrong.
For example i have this string "0601",

```
var _stringNumber = '0601';
var _number = Number('0601'); // result is 601
```

i need `_number = 0601` but result is `601`.

what is the solution?

Comment: You can't. Numbers ignores leading 0s.

Comment: I don't think it is possible. I would be interested to know why you need it this way

Comment: Why do you think you need this?  What is the use case?

Comment: It's the way numbers work since they discovered them centuries ago.

Comment: Leading zero's have no meaning in whole numbers, nor does it have an impact on output from a calculation so there is no point in having it except for display purposes in which case you would keep it a string, or create a string representation prepending a 0 during display

Comment: A thing which is a number stores a _numeric value_, not a visual representation of that value. There is no "leading zero" in a value.

Comment: Can I ask, why you want it so bad ?

Comment: I have to init ngbCalendar in "YYYY/MM/DD" format and year, month and day in ngbDateStruct  are in number. var ngbDateStruct = { day: day, month:month, year: year };. how can i do this?

Comment: Then you just set the numbers, if it expects each property to actually be a number it is not going to expect a leading 0.

Comment: Classic [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/138482) — you _asked_ how to keep the leading zero but that was your own proposed solution to your _real problem_: how can you init your ngbCalendar. You should delete this question and ask a new one for what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: stephen-p its ok. i just answered jcalz and thirueswaran-rajagopalan question.

Comment: **Q:** Convert string to number in typescript without losing leading zero without using an array solution - what is the solution? ... **A:** There is no solution, this can't be done. ** ... While that doesn't solve the problem that you are trying to solve, the question you asked _has been answered_. Stackoverflow is not a discussion board or forum, it is a _Question & Answer_ site. To solve your problem about initializing ngbCalendar you should _ask a **different** question._

Answer (score 4):

A number is a number; there is no way to distinguish `3` from `03` because these are the same number.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple for loop

```js
let stringNumber = '0601';
let tempNumbers = [];

for(let i = 0; i < stringNumber.length; i++) {
   tempNumbers.push(+stringNumber[i]);
}

let number = tempNumbers.join('');

// Result : 0601
```

Answer (score -1):

***Make an Object***

```
var MyNumber = function(stringNum) {
    var visualNumber = stringNum;
    var actualNumber = Number(visualNumber);
}
```

Usage:

```
var num = MyNumber('0601');
var dummyNum = 65;
var resultNum = dummyNum + num.actualNumber;
console.log(resultNum); // 666... (O.o) <- Oh noes
```